# Dependency injection not working properly for my ASP.NET Core MVVM Blazor application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor, repository-pattern

I am having trouble trying to apply dependency injection. After a lot of research and looking at various videos on YouTube and answers on Stack overflow, my ITaskRepository keeps returning a null instead of it being an instance of my repository. Looking at my code it seems I have added all the right things to make dependency injection work.

My Base Repository interface

```cs
using portfolio_backend.Data.Base;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories.Base
{
    public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseModel
    {
        void Add(TEntity model);
        void Delete(TEntity model);
        bool Exists(int Id);
        TEntity Get(int Id);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
        void Update(int Id, TEntity model);
    }
}
```

My BaseRepository class

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using portfolio_backend.Data;
using portfolio_backend.Data.Base;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories.Base
{
    public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseModel
    {
        protected PortfolioContext _context;

        public BaseRepository(PortfolioContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Add(TEntity model)
        {
            if (!Exists(model.Id))
            {
                _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(model);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity model)
        {
            if (Exists(model.Id))
            {
                _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(model);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public bool Exists(int Id)
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().Any(model => model.Id == Id);
        }

        public TEntity Get(int Id)
        {
           return _context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(model => model.Id == Id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }

        public void Update(int Id, TEntity model)
        {
            var modelToFind = Get(Id);
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Update(modelToFind);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

My ITaskRepository interface

```cs
using portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories.Base;
using portfolio_backend.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories
{
    public interface ITaskRepository : IBaseRepository<Task>
    {
        IEnumerable<Task> GetTaskByProjects(int ProjectId);
    }
}
```

TaskRepository Implementation

```cs
using portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories.Base;
using portfolio_backend.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories
{
    public class TaskRepository : BaseRepository<Task>, ITaskRepository
    {
        public TaskRepository(PortfolioContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public IEnumerable<Task> GetTaskByProjects(int ProjectId)
        {
            return _context.Tasks.OrderByDescending(task => task.Project.Id == ProjectId).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

My Startup class:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories.Base;
using portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories;
using portfolio_backend.Data;
using Blazorise;
using Blazorise.Bootstrap;
using Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome;

namespace portfolio_backend.Presentation
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<PortfolioContext>(options => 
                options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("portfolio")));

            services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
            services.AddScoped<ITaskRepository, TaskRepository>();

            services.AddBlazorise(options =>{
                options.ChangeTextOnKeyPress = true;})
                      .AddBootstrapProviders()
                      .AddFontAwesomeIcons();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.ApplicationServices
                  .UseBootstrapProviders()
                  .UseFontAwesomeIcons();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to apply dependency injection for the following two classes:

Tasks.razor.cs ( a code-behind for a Blazor component)

```cs
using portfolio_backend.Business;
using portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories;

namespace portfolio_backend.Presentation.Pages
{
    public partial class Tasks
    {
        private ITaskRepository _taskRepository;
        private TaskViewModel _taskViewModel => new TaskViewModel(_taskRepository);

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
             _taskViewModel.SeedTasks();
        }

    }
}
```

and the view model for this component

```cs
using portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories;
using portfolio_backend.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace portfolio_backend.Business
{
    public class TaskViewModel
    {
  
        private ITaskRepository _taskRepository {get; set;}
        private List<Task> _allTasks;

        public TaskViewModel(ITaskRepository repository)
        {
            _taskRepository = repository;
        }

        public List<Task> AllTasks
        {
            get => _allTasks;
            set => _taskRepository.GetAll();
        }

        public void SeedTasks() 
        {
            _taskRepository.Add( new Task { Description = "Task 1"} );
            _taskRepository.Add(new Task { Description = "Task 2" });
            _taskRepository.Add(new Task { Description = "Task 3" });
        }

    }
}
```

_taskRepository always returns null, and this is the error message that appears:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

what can I do to solve this? or how can I apply DI in a better way under these circumstances?

UPDATE:

I made the following changes based on one of the suggested solutions in the comments:

```cs
using portfolio_backend.Business;
using portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories;

namespace portfolio_backend.Presentation.Pages
{
    public partial class Tasks
    {
        private ITaskRepository _taskRepository;
        private TaskViewModel _taskViewModel;

        public Tasks(ITaskRepository repository)
        {
            _taskRepository = repository;
            _taskViewModel = new TaskViewModel(_taskRepository);
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
             _taskViewModel.SeedTasks();
        }

    }
}
```

This will trigger the following error:

```
MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'portfolio_backend.Presentation.Pages.Tasks'.
```

As the error suggested I added an additional parameterless constructor

```cs
using portfolio_backend.Business;
using portfolio_backend.Business.Repositories;

namespace portfolio_backend.Presentation.Pages
{
    public partial class Tasks
    {
        private ITaskRepository _taskRepository;
        private TaskViewModel _taskViewModel;

        public Tasks()
        {
        }

        public Tasks(ITaskRepository repository)
        {
            _taskRepository = repository;
            _taskViewModel = new TaskViewModel(_taskRepository);
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
             _taskViewModel.SeedTasks();
        }

    }
}
```

The change above created the same issue with the taskRepository being null.

Comment: yep I just tried it, and it the _taskRepository will still return null

Comment: I also added the error message that appears when I am debugging my code.

Comment: You didn't change Tasks to use constructor injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two main challenges in this scenario.

The first one was that I didn't design my app properly. What I mean by that is that I initially intended to use dependency injection on an instance of my repository to be able to create an instance of my TaskViewModel in my code behind like this.

```cs
public Tasks(ITaskRepository repository)
{
  _taskRepository = repository;
 _taskViewModel = new TaskViewModel(_taskRepository);
}
```

A better way to do it which was part of my solution was to also create an interface for my TaskViewModel so I can use dependency injection in my Blazor component code-behind. The TaskViewModel itself should have had an instance of my repository through dependency injection.

ITaskViewModel:

```cs
    public interface ITaskViewModel : IBaseViewModel<Task>
    {
        List<Task> AllTasks { get; set; }

        void SeedTasks();
    }
```

My Implementation for the TaskViewModel

```cs
    public class TaskViewModel : BaseViewModel<Task>, ITaskViewModel
    {

        private ITaskRepository _taskRepository;
        private List<Task> _allTasks;

        public TaskViewModel(ITaskRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {
            _taskRepository = repository;
        }

        public List<Task> AllTasks
        {
            get => _allTasks;
            set 
            {
                _allTasks = value;
            }
        }

        public void SeedTasks() 
        {
            var task1 = new Task { Description = "Task 1" };
            var task2 = new Task { Description = "Task 2" };
            var task3 = new Task { Description = "Task 3" };

            _taskRepository.Add(task1);
            _taskRepository.Add(task2);
            _taskRepository.Add(task3);
        }

    }
```

Component registration on the ConfigureServices method of the Startup.cs file

```cs
services.AddScoped<ITaskViewModel, TaskViewModel>();
```

The 2nd problem was that I could not use the constructor or the member property approach to use dependency injection in a Blazor component code-behind. Not sure if the same applies to razor page code behind, but the way you use dependency inject for a Blazor component code-behind is by using the Inject attribute

Tasks.razor.cs

```cs
 [Inject]
 private ITaskViewModel _viewModel { get; set; }
```

Make sure you also have the following Nuget package installed for the Inject attribute to work.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
```

Answer (score 0):

`_taskRepository` must be either a property or a constructor parameter. You have it as a class member. It can't be injected like that.

Comment: I am not too sure I understand. I added a default get set to the _taskRepository to make it a property but it still returned a null value. I am still new to all of this. Could you give an example of how this could be done correctly?

Comment: Can you show the code you added?  Also, I'm not sure property injection is even supported in ASP.Net, especially by default. Try using constructor injection.

Comment: it still didn't work, I posted an update using your suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your dependency in  ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) of your startup file :

```
services.AddScoped<ITaskRepository, TaskRepository>();

or 

services.AddTransient<ITaskRepository, TaskRepository>();
```

You have to decide what fits you app better.

Answer (score 0):

Following the edits you've made to your initial question, it seems that your are using Dependency Injection mechanisms on a class which is not registered : **Tasks**. How is this class implemented?

If you want to use DI on a specific class, you should register it as you did with ITaskRepository for example.

Add the following line to your ConfigureServices() method :

```
        services.AddScoped<Tasks>();
```

Comment: This class is actually a code behind a razor page. It wasn't implemented  in any particular fashion but I will definitely give it a try.